# Upload a file using php curl into the backendless files storage

Tags: php, rest, backendless

am trying to upload a file(it could be image or a document) into the ‘backendless files’ through a php form.

I have created a new folder in the backendless files(root) in the name of ‘Uploads’ where i want all the uploaded files to be saved.

I have a basic code through which i am unable to upload the file and i need some help.

Backendless Version v5.2.14

Client SDK (REST)

Application ID :30BB5E5E-6AE8-53E0-FFE4-87303ACE0300

```
<?php
    //get the incident id from the url and if its missing throw an error    
    if( !isset($_GET['incident']) && !isset($_POST['incident']) )
        {
            echo "<script> alert('Incident id is missing.'); window.location.href = '#'; </script>";  
        }
    //set the incident id to $id            
    if( isset($_GET['incident']) )
        {
                // $id = hexdec($_GET['incident']) ^ 42; 
            $ID = $_GET['incident'];  //to test form without xor 
        }   

    // //Check if incident id is present in the Incident table          
    //   $user_info = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM Incident WHERE IncidentID = {$id} ");

    //retrieve the data from the backendless table and check if the incident id is present in it
    $service_url1 = 'https://api.backendless.com/<app-key>/<rest-api-key>/data/Incident';
    $curl1 = curl_init($service_url1);
    curl_setopt($curl1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $curl_response1 = curl_exec($curl1);
    if ($curl_response1 === false) {
        $info1 = curl_getinfo($curl1);
        curl_close($curl1);
        die('error occured during curl exec. Additioanl info: ' . var_export($info1));
    }
    curl_close($curl1);
    //getting the array which is stored in $curl_response1, putting it in decoded and pulling out only the incident id field and arranging it properly.
    $decoded = json_decode($curl_response1);
    $res1 = array_column($decoded, 'IncidentID');
    $res2 = implode("', '", $res1);

    // //displaying the results for learning purpose 
    //      echo "<br>res2 = ".$res2;
    //      echo "<br>ID  = ".$ID ; 
    //      echo "<br>res1 = ".$res1." : ";
    //      print_r($res1); 

    //checking if the incident id is present in the array(res1)
    if (!in_array($ID, $res1)) 
        {
            echo "<script> alert('Incident id not found.'); window.location.href = '#'; </script>"; 
        }       


$errmsg = '';
if (isset($_POST['Submit']))
{
    $filename = $_FILES['uploadoc']['name'];
    $filedata = $_FILES['uploadoc']['tmp_name'];
    $filesize = $_FILES['uploadoc']['size'];
    $filetype = $_FILES['uploadoc']['type'];

    $url = "https://api.backendless.com/<app-key>/<rest-api-key>/files/Uploads/".$filename;// e.g. http://localhost/myuploader/upload.php // request URL

    if ($filedata != '')
    {
        $headers = array("Content-Type:multipart/form-data"); // cURL headers for file uploading
        $postfields = array("filedata" => $filedata, "filename" => $filename);
        $ch = curl_init();
        $options = array(
            CURLOPT_URL => $url,
            CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
            CURLOPT_POST => 1,
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postfields,
            CURLOPT_INFILESIZE => $filesize,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
        ); // cURL options
        curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
        curl_exec($ch);
        if(!curl_errno($ch))
        {
            $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
            if ($info['http_code'] == 200)
                $errmsg = "File uploaded successfully";
        }
        else
        {
            $errmsg = curl_error($ch);
        }
        curl_close($ch);
    }
    else
    {
        $errmsg = "Please select the file";
    }
}

?>

<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .upload-doc-submit{margin-top: 20px;}
    </style>
</head>
<body style="text-align:left;" onload="StartTimers();" onclick="ResetTimers();">
<div>
    <form method="post" id="upload-doc" onsubmit="return validate();" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <table>
            <tr>
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap uploadoc">
                        <td>
                            <label>Upload Document : </label>
                            <input type="file" name="uploadoc" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-file wpcf7-validates-as-required" accept=".docx,.jpg,.doc" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" required="">
                        </td>
                    </span>
                </div>  
            </tr>   

            <tr>
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                        <td align="center" valign="middle">
                            <input type="hidden" name="incident" value="$id">
                            <input  type="submit" id="btnSubmit"  value="Submit" name="Submit" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit upload-doc-submit center">
                        </td>
                    </span>
                </div>  
            </tr>
        </table> 

    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>

<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(  function()
    {
        jQuery("#userregistration").validate
            ({
                ignore: ":hidden",
                rules: 
                    {
                        uploadoc: 
                            {
                                required : true
                            }       

                    },
                messages: 
                    {
                        uploadoc: 
                            {   
                                required : "Please choose a file." 
                            }       
                    },
            });

    });
</script>

<?php

if (isset($_POST['Submit']))
    {
        echo " <br />  <br />  <div style='text-align:center'>or</div>";
        echo '<br />  <br />  <th><strong><u><center><a target="_blank" href="javascript:window.close();">Click here to return.</a></center></u></th>';
    }   

?>
```

Expected Behavior:
1.I want the form to display a window where i have to upload the file which i want to be saved into the backendless files. (done)

2.I want a new folder to be created in the name of the person uploading the file,which will be in the ‘Uploads’ folder.

3.The new file should go in that new folder.

Actual Behavior:
For now it doesn’t give any error and also doesn’t upload the file, its like a dead form.

Comment: Why is that service called "backendless"? It _is_ simply a backend...

Comment: @arkascha  im talking about https://backendless.com/documentation/api-engine/apieng_overview.htm

Comment: I know. That is why I asked. The name makes no sense. It is pure marketing speak.